# [Galaxy S8} How to set default alarm sound?

Tags: alarm, samsung-galaxy-s-8

There is no option in settings. I have also tried setting it like in the thread: [How to change the default alarm sound?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/78335/how-to-change-the-default-alarm-sound?newreg=ebf21e6a119643c9aef728c6ec97c472)
but the method presented is not working for me. I get "set success" message, but still have android default alarm sound. (Even after restarting phone)

I have no idea how can I get around this. I would prefer to use default clock app.

Answer (score 1):

When you're setting your alarm, you can set the song, that is one of solutions

[image: here]

Comment: I mean, I want it default when I add new alarm